# Add data starting with first black row

Tags: excel, vba

Step 1:I have a VBA code which insert data in "sheet2" from "sheet1" based on some conditions (using a loop).

Step 2: I need to create a new code which loops the created "sheet2" and add at the end of it part of the rows created on step 1 ""sheet2" based on some conditions

Eg:
I created on Step 1 - "Sheet2" the rows presented on the image

[image]
I want to introduce at the end of this only the rows which contains on column B named CONT CONTABIL CREDIT "15.IB" by replacing the value from column G  named VALOARE with its value (in this case 25,00) with it's value * 12,5% (25,00 * 12,5% = 3,13).
The new result being as presented on the image (please find the added row in grey):
[image]

! My issue:

1. I want the loop to be static on the first image (not to go to the last row which will contain the new row presented on the second image)
2. How to insert below the first image rows, new rows with the data but with the value calculated as presented above.

Thanks in advance.

Please find below my attempt:

```
exp_conta_lastRow = exp_conta.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
For j = 2 To exp_conta_lastRow
    If InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "13.IO") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IA") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IB") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IC") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.ID") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IH") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.II") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IJ") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IK") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IL") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IM") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IN") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IP") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IR") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IS") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IV") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IW") Or _
        InStr(exp_conta.Cells(j, 2), "15.IX") Then
            exp_conta.Cells(exp_conta_lastRow + j - 1, 1) = "test" 'copy of the entire row and on the "Valoare column" * 12,5%, instead of the existing value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I do  not understand what value to use in order to replace 25 from column G:G... Both pictures show 25...

Comment: @FaneDuru I want to add a new row with the same data but instead of 25 as in the original row to have a new value which is 25 (in our case) * 12,5%. The idea is to have the rows with the premium and other rows with the same info but which contains only the tax value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testInsertRowsAtTheEnd()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastR1 As Long, lastR2 As Long, arrC As Variant
  Dim i As Long, arr As Variant, arr1 As Variant
  
  Set sh1 = ActiveSheet         ' use here your necessary sheet (the one where from the lines will be copied)
  Set sh2 = Worksheets("Shet2") 'idem as above in terms of naming...
  arr = Split("13.IO,15.IA,15.IB,15.IC,15.ID,15.IH,15.II,15.IJ,15.IL,15.IM,15.IN,15.IP,15.IR,15.IS,15.IV,15.IW,15.IX", ",")
  
  lastR1 = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  For i = 2 To lastR1
    If issOK(sh1.Range("B" & i).Value, arr) Then
        lastR2 = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1 'first empty row
        arrC = sh1.Range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Value: arrC(1, 7) = arrC(1, 7) * 12.5 / 100
        sh2.Range("A" & lastR2).Resize(1, UBound(arrC, 2)).Value = arrC
    End If
  Next i
End Sub

Function issOK(strVal As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean ' it also accepts strings
   Dim El As Variant
   If IsArray(arr) Then
        For Each El In arr
             If InStr(strVal, El) > 0 Then issOK = True: Exit Function
        Next
   Else
        If InStr(strVal, arr) > 0 Then issOK = True
   End If
End Function
```

Edited:
Added the function able to process the strings to be taken in consideration by iteration condition, as in your code example, not only the string requested in the question description. You can add/change the values between commas, according to your need.

In order to test and better build your understanding about the function way of working, please use the next way:

```
Sub testissOK()
  Dim arr As Variant, arr1 As Variant
  arr = Split("13.IO,15.IA,15.IB,15.IC,15.ID,15.IH,15.II,15.IJ,15.IL,15.IM,15.IN,15.IP,15.IR,15.IS,15.IV,15.IW,15.IX", ",")
  arr1 = Split("test1,test2", ",")
  
  Debug.Print issOK("Rupere13.IO2000", arr)
  Debug.Print issOK("acesta este un test", arr1), issOK("acesttest1esteOK", arr1)
  Debug.Print issOK("test2detestare", "test2"), issOK("test2detestare", "test1")
  If issOK("testscriere13.IOetcetera", arr) Then
      Debug.Print "Este, nene..."
  End If
  If issOK("testscrieretest1etcetera", arr1) Then
       Debug.Print "OK si-aici..."
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i'm not sure I got the function. If arr contains one of the values the function will return true. If not exit function? I wanna add more conditions like this. Eg: if is "18.IT" then value * 2,5% etc. I have more tax % depending of the product. Also, the function needs to be used on thecode above. M'I right?

Comment: @Alin-Iustinian Toderita: In a way (only)... I mean, `Instr` find one of the array elements **it make the function True** and exits it. If not, the iteration goes up to the last element, but not finding a match, the function is `False`. In order to do what you say, I will adapt the concept. I mean, I will create the array in the main code and pass it to the function as parameter. In this way, according to the passed array you can set different conditions, using the same function. I will post the updated answer in some minutes...

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim r As Long, n As Long, i As Long
    Dim c As Integer, j As Integer
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(2)
    Set toWs = Sheets(1)
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)
    For i = 2 To r
        If InStr(vDB(i, 2), "13.IO") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IA") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IB") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IC") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.ID") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IH") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.II") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IJ") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IK") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IL") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IM") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IN") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IP") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IR") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IS") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IV") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IW") Or _
            InStr(vDB(i, 2), "15.IX") Then
            
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To c, 1 To n)
            For j = 1 To c
                vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
            Next j
            vR(7, n) = vR(7, n) * 0.125
        End If
    Next i
    Set Target = toWs.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    If n Then
        Target.Resize(n, c) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End If
    
End Sub
```